# MS Word changes relative links back to absolute links

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

We have some documentation files in our company that go to customers, and I noticed that some links are saved as absolute references, so for example to \server001\Files..., which of course won't work for customers. So I wrote code that takes all files in a folder, and changes the links from absolute references to local references.

```
toc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathFile, true);
var baseUri = new Uri(pathFile, UriKind.Absolute);

IEnumerable<HyperlinkRelationship> all_hr = toc.MainDocumentPart.HyperlinkRelationships;
for (int index = 0; index < all_hr.Count(); index++)
{
    HyperlinkRelationship hr = all_hr.ElementAt(index);
    string link = hr.Uri.OriginalString.Replace("%20", " ");

    if (!(link.EndsWith(".doc") || link.EndsWith(".docx")))
        continue;

    if (hr.Uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
    {
        var newHr = new Uri(link, UriKind.Absolute);
        link = baseUri.MakeRelativeUri(newHr).OriginalString;
    }

    log.Info("Changed: " + hr.Uri.OriginalString + " to: " + link + " in file: " + sourceFile);
    var hyperlinkRelationshipId = hr.Id;
    toc.MainDocumentPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(hr);

    try
    {
        toc.MainDocumentPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri(link, UriKind.Relative), false, hyperlinkRelationshipId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // This would be reached if link is still absolute. Never called.
    }
}

toc.Save();
toc.Close();
```

When I debug this, it finds absolute links just fine, and they are all stored back as relative links.

But if I then take a look at the files that were "fixed", suddenly different references that I did not even touch in the code are changed, and absolute again (to `file:///\\Server001\Files\...`).

Is my understanding of references in Word false, or what might be happening here?

Sample log output:

```
16:49:43,738 [DOC2PDF] INFO - Changed: file:///\\Server001\Files\Main\RSL.doc to: ..\Main\RSL.doc in file: file:///\\Server001\Files\Main\INDEX.doc
```

Comment: Does this happen on some relative links or all relative links? What's the point of *relative URLs* in a Word document? What web site would they refer to? Are you sure the change isn't made by the code that saves the Word document as PDF?

Comment: If you wanted a PDF, why are you creating a Word document?

Comment: The customer basically gets a load of Word Documents, and they point to other Word documents in the same folder. The real code also checks for any weblink, and dismisses those. All links are only to the same folder, or a subfolder, and the customer gets the whole folder structure. But some links suddenly change to what the path was on the system creating the files. It only happens to some relative links. Like, 98% of links are okay and relative, but a few... not. And I do not know why.

Comment: Oh, DOC2PDF, I was wondering how you came up with PDF. The software has 2 modes -> convert all documents recursively to PDF and change the links internally accordingly, and the second, which is what I am talking about here, fixing all absolute links. And the fixing links just does not work for unknown reasons.